# Function lookup table with generic: TS infers the function type as a union of all possible function types in the lookup table

Tags: typescript

[Minimal Repro Example on Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhBOA3AlgY2gXigcgM4JXQEFsoAfHfJNCAIWwCgB6JqASSlXggENgIAJlB5QAZgFcAdqmDIA9pKjAeAIwA20YHKXwek3KLnwAtlGSSw44Eu0iA4gEUAMlAiSBYOeetaoYHrrGEPzwuGJGrjyoABZQVIQQAHQMDKCQUHYAjmpsFlZQWADewiqoAgBcccDw5gDmANxxckEAYsgQahVVNZK1UAC%209Slp0AAquvqGJrmWwC1SMvL6BVCFDFBxBDRElQAU5rOVWTl5wACUBQB8q5vUxG0dXbjVdQNDG-E0tHsHVkfZMysFww12Kkh4QUqzx6DVuCVoD06UJevTeDEGKVQCmeOj0BiMxkBcwWsmxo1UGkq4zxU0Jp3m0lJyyK6zh2x%20p2BoNZG24wHE8EUaw2IrZ93aSLMp0SqjKABoeWiNv0FR8tuhvlB9pyrqtFXyBULFRtwZCcGo1NhVaKxXREV1fsBErhmhB7YqMcqFRiWOxONw%20IJhJI5MBoggxCSlkoKZptGo5HIANZQcRgSOMpZhXzGHhJ6CoHgW7PaMPIMKfdDlYbgaAAYSLajgdzdUexAB5Rq4AB78dxhfMgOSiKDUyYEokMxbY64sjYAbQA0lLRwBdPaKwsWgAKAQhwQQuEqACVgobRrXOxN8dN6W39EvV5dWVyoNv4M1yxB28VuLhxGowDIjCAyXEMGIMFi%20jWFuTbqq2mZkrGlQNhazYJFOTK4O2rKDsOo7XrSk73rgDCznqaotjswi4CA0harBu6BAeoSvsKIoGoKb4fsYX6JH%20chqIgEC7L%20ED-oBlSMXuQQhLgzrwUQ9oDGc7wDNalZ0JUPC0fRuzScxclsfqZ5ce%20n74Px4mCcJolQH%20AFAZwjZMfuckKS2CISkI-SqayKrokMDASIhii1ME6E0AAcvuuyDsBdRnJUkXoBRHGmYog4FBgWAAEQ8LlUAAPyUIppCVHg8H0OBKQ6XRqAZtOYXZAAou4njeNqhwZACOrsRsUE4ppKzhcAKUQDFQS7PluV%20Zu2I%20IRE6nCs1Q0stsyYVm5LqBA86aauakDQtzk7jJLFhFga3jresxdUCQWioNMGNuNKyweNW1Ibt%203wYdiq%20qM4ZQGo5jQCoHRyAA7lA0Q6cISi1q48AfvA83QVAchWLMKw8FDPDIC9aHwfpLnnUZR1QCZ-JcVjwCzDVDB1fRIVNVAtSte1XiSMAABM91OccRIXP1nAnZpyXwSNEXwZNIkzXNoq%20twkB8K8YbQLg%205iwI0A8KIIRQOCKPQ68AjQ4oAAGmmW1Aub5tmwMjMjqPs7Y%20MgHKUAqPkHCSBAQa%20DwiBeEIKvBITSzJKKyAjrsw05XlmlELNaU2mLGPXTedI41dS23VYX36DtGi-S2-3p8dGMGW5h6rfnOdWALiuV89p1wS272vfBRe4CXe0HZTSusED0Cg-73uQzDcNhCIzsIKjxoim3dO58I%20OE%20342k2dhmHi36ecYoq9WJT-SuGo%20A3L6sdagnOWlZ52Ai0vVc4lnRErXn60F8SoV97GMuCQK6txOjXWSddv43UbsAZuj1QHV27p3LAH0e4kX7kAmgID04r2xvkLAeMCZEw7gkHeahXIQNYvAw%20GVMZ4OAGfdEQA)

**Background:**

There are two microservices: `serviceA` and `serviceB`

```
type Service = 'serviceA' | 'serviceB'
```

I created a function table to transform input to a GQL endpoint to parameters for each service.

```
type GqlInput = { abcd: string; someField: string };

type TransformInputFunctions = {
  serviceA: (input: GqlInput) => { serviceAField: string };
  serviceB: (input: GqlInput) => { name: string; serviceBField: string };
};

const transformInputFunctionsTable: TransformInputFunctions = {
  serviceA: (input) => {
    return {
      serviceAField: input.abcd,
    };
  },
  serviceB: (input) => {
    return {
      name: 'll',
      serviceBField: input.someField
    };
  },
};
```

I created another function table to look up functions to make calls to this service:

```
type CallServiceFunctions<T extends keyof TransformInputFunctions> = {
  [K in T]: (
    callParameters: ReturnType<TransformInputFunctions[K]>
  ) => Promise<{ result: string }>;
};

const callServiceFunctionsTable: CallServiceFunctions<
  keyof TransformInputFunctions
> = {
  serviceA: async (callParameters) => {
    return Promise.resolve({ result: callParameters.serviceAField });
  },
  serviceB: async (callParameters) => {
    return Promise.resolve({ result: callParameters.serviceBField });
  },
};
```

Note that I used the `ReturnType` of the input function as the type for `callParameters`.

**Issue:**

The following function has a type error

```
async function gqlEndpoint(input: GqlInput) {
    const service = getServiceName("a");

    const transformInput = transformInputFunctionsTable[service];
    const callParameters = transformInput(input);

    const callService = callServiceFunctionsTable[service];
    const output = await callService(callParameters); // callParameters has a type error

    return output;
}
```

The only way to make the type error go away is to narrow down the `service` variable like below, but I have to repeat the same code, and in my actual implementation, there are a lot more than just two services, so it will be a lot of repetition. The point of doing this was to not repeat the code.

```
async function gqlEndpoint(input: GqlInput) {
    if (service === "serviceA") {
        const transformInput = transformInputFunctionsTable[service];
        const callParameters = transformInput(input);

        const callService = callServiceFunctionsTable[service];
        // The line below has a type error
        const output = await callService(callParameters);

        return output;
    } else { // if (service === 'serviceB') {
        // ...repeat the exact same code as the previous if block
    }
}
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Argument of type '{ serviceAField: string; } | { name: string; serviceBField: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ serviceAField: string; } & { name: string; serviceBField: string; }'.
  Type '{ serviceAField: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ serviceAField: string; } & { name: string; serviceBField: string; }'.
    Type '{ serviceAField: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ name: string; serviceBField: string; }': name, serviceBField(2345)
```

**More type info:**
I hovered over variables and found the following type information:

```
// from `const callParameters = transformInput(input);`
const callParameters: {
    serviceAField: string;
} | {
    name: string;
    serviceBField: string;
}

// from `const callService = callServiceFunctionsTable[service];`
const callService: ((callParameters: {
    serviceAField: string;
}) => Promise<{
    result: string;
}>) | ((callParameters: {
    name: string;
    serviceBField: string;
}) => Promise<{
    result: string;
}>)

// from `const output = await callService(callParameters);`
const callService: (callParameters: {
    serviceAField: string;
} & {
    name: string;
    serviceBField: string;
}) => Promise<{
    result: string;
}>
```

TypeScript tries to infer the type of `callService` based on the possible types of service. However, because service can be any key of `TransformInputFunctions`, TypeScript infers the type of `callService` as a union of all possible function types in `CallServiceFunctions`.

How can I cleanly narrow down the type of `callParameters` so that TypeScript can apply the more specific type for the `service`? I want to fix this as cleanly as possible. I appreciate your help!